# How to get more information about powershell cmdlets?

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-3.0

I've been googling around for hours now about the `Get-WebConfiguration` cmdlet in `Web-Administration` to no avail. The MSDN source for it does not explain **what** the -Metadata parameter accepts as input. I'm running this command in a deploy script:

`Set-WebConfiguration -PSPath IIS:\ -Filter /system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication -Metadata overrideMode -value Allow`

I'm developing a library that reads these values and alerts users if their environment does not conform to the spec, so I'm trying to use:

`Get-WebConfiguration -PSPath IIS:\ -Filter /system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication -Metadata overrideMode`

But I'm getting the error: `A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts 
argument 'overrideMode'.`

*I literally just set this exact parameter using this exact syntax*!

How do I find out more information about parameters in powershell? Is there a cmdlet for this or am I just using Get-WebConfiguration wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific error you get is caused by the fact that the `-Metadata` parameter is a switch - it doesn't accept any arguments.

When you specify the `-Metadata` switch, the object returned contains a `Metadata` property.

To get the value of `overrideMode` do:

```
(Get-WebConfiguration -Filter "/node/filter" -Metadata).Metadata.overrideMode
```

---

## Discovering Command details:

(I'm using `Test-Path` as an example, but this will work for any cmdlet)

You can always get the most basic information about cmdlet **syntax** from `Get-Command -Syntax`:

```
PS C:\> Get-Command Test-Path -Syntax

Test-Path [-Path] <string[]> [-Filter <string>] [-Include <string[]>] [-Exclude <string[]>] [-PathType <TestPathType>]
[-IsValid] [-Credential <pscredential>] [-UseTransaction] [-OlderThan <datetime>] [-NewerThan <datetime>]
[<CommonParameters>]

Test-Path -LiteralPath <string[]> [-Filter <string>] [-Include <string[]>] [-Exclude <string[]>] [-PathType
<TestPathType>] [-IsValid] [-Credential <pscredential>] [-UseTransaction] [-OlderThan <datetime>] [-NewerThan
<datetime>] [<CommonParameters>]
```

`Get-Command` returns a `CommandInfo` object, and you can use this to inspect the parameters in depth.

As an example, let's take a look at the `Get-WebConfiguration -Metadata` parameter:

```
PS C:\> (Get-Command Get-WebConfiguration).Parameters["Metadata"]

Name            : Metadata
ParameterType   : System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter
ParameterSets   : {[__AllParameterSets, System.Management.Automation.ParameterSetMetadata]}
IsDynamic       : False
Aliases         : {}
Attributes      : {__AllParameterSets}
SwitchParameter : True
```

Here we can see that `-Metadata` is in fact a switch (notice the `SwitchParameter : True` property)

To retrieve **documentation** about a cmdlet, you can always use the `Get-Help` cmdlet to get a perldoc/manpage-like output about a specific cmdlet. Since the documentation is just text, you can pipe it to `more` to step through it (again, much like a manpage or a perldoc):

```
# Get a basic summary
Get-Help Test-Path

# Get more comprehensive summary
Get-Help Test-Path -Detailed

# Get the full documentation including examples
Get-Help Test-Path -Full

# Get just the examples
Get-Help Test-Path -Examples

# Get the help section about a specific parameter
Get-Help Test-Path -Parameter Path
```

Comment: This is a great resource post, however the resources and cmdlets do not have the information I am trying to discover (the allowed values for metadata or what is wrong with the cmdlet I'm using). Do you have any other resources that might lead me further?

Comment: @CBauer If you look at the output from `Get-Command Get-WebConfiguration -Syntax`, you'll see the `MetaData` parameter does not accept any argument - it's a switch. That's why you get the error, PowerShell cannot bind the string "overrideMode" to the `MetaData` parameter

Comment: Thank you Mathias! When I read switch I didn't realize it was a powershell specific concept because I program in c# and switches are just fancy ifs, so I thought it took in a normal string and figured out what to do with it. My problem was that I didn't RTFM.